# How to ignore/block someone?

Tags: support, users

Is there a way to block someone from seeing, answering, commenting or voting my questions? In other words a way to make me completely invisible to that person and vice-versa?

Comment: On the top why you want to do this ?

Comment: Because there're some people I consider rude/offensive and I don't want to see them or their comments in my questions. This kind of people usually don't answer but go around downvoting and give offensive comments instead of trying to help or contributing constructive criticism. Flagging doesn't guarantee next time they're not going to abuse me again. I really think it's better to have this feature.

Comment: No. There is flagging. Example?

Comment: But flag orr post on meta works perfactly .... show us who is rude or offensive to you ...

Comment: As a side comment, I think I know the person you're referring to, and I don't think they intended to come off as being rude. Sometimes terse comments can read that way, because it's hard to express a more subtle tone there. They apologized for their initial response, and I've cleaned up the comments involved here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, except for chat. Stack Exchange is not a social network.

If you received comments that you didn't welcome, either ignore them and move on or flag them. In chat, you can ignore people by clicking on their avatar and selecting "ignore this user (everywhere)".

Comment: You may ignore the user but presumably they still see your chat and may reply to it etc., unseen by you?